# Changing look how Wordpress is sending mail

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make Wordpress as email sender and here is a problem I'm facing:

I'm using XYZ Newsletter plugin for sending emails. But when the person gets the email, in the persons email check program in the email field i get a whole server name instead of address.

For ex. jkdo@arboga.hostingas.in; on behalf of; Admin infoatmydomaindotcom

I need to be only the email address

And this is the same when Wordpress itself is sending a letter.
May be you know where to change it?

Comment: which plugin are you using ?

Comment: It seems, **From** parameter is not set in `mail` function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to configure "WP Mail SMTP" plugin and configure it with SMTP rather than use simple mail from server.
And If you still want to use server mail if you have WHM then you may change Host from there , if no WHM, You should contact hosting provider if they provide it.

Comment: This is not answer, you could suggest this as an comment.